# XPath to text node whose ancestor has a descendant that contains specific text string

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to find the xpath to a text node that follows the immediately preceding text node in the DOM - but they aren't siblings and their xpath relationship can change.

I'm trying to find the dollar amount, which changes. There is a unique ID up top. The unique text and the dollar amount are the only two pieces of text within their closest div ancestor. I want to find the unique text, then move up to the closest div ancestor, then return the text string within that div ancestor that contains "$".
I want to make sure it's returning the CLOSEST div ancestor (not the FIRST div under uniqueID) because there are many div ancestors where this could be true.

I use ancestor and descendent because the number of elements between uniqueID and text and uniqueID and $ amount changes.

my best guess (that doesn't work):
//text()[contains(.,"$")][ancestor::div[1]//*[text()[contains(.,"uniqueText")]][ancestor::div[@id="uniqueID"]]

I think that 'div[1]' is returning the top div though, not the closest div above the uniqueText

```
<div id="unique">
    <div>
        <h4></h4>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <span>
                            <span>
                                <span>uniqueText
                                </span>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <p>$xxx</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear (and the html sample is invalid), but if I understand you correctly and you want to start from the text and get the $ amount where these are both under the closest common `<div>` ancestor, and the $ amount is contained within a single `<p>` tag under that common ancestor, try this on your actual html

```
div[@id="unique"]//span[contains(./text()[1],"uniqueText")]/ancestor::div[1]/div[contains(.//p/text(),"$")]//p/text()
```

and see if it works.